# Discord Bot RGB Role Python

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to write a Bot that changes the color of a Role on a server every 1 minute. What should I do?
The bot is supposed to do this only on one server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
while True:
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='ROLE_NAME')
    await role.edit(colour=discord.Colour.random())
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

(This was made for `ctx`, if you got `message` just change the `ctx` to `message`, also you need to import asyncio as extra module)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this by background task, but i think it's not good idea to do that role :/ and maybe your bot will be get ratelimit from discord

Comment: Yes, it probably is no good idea, but the bot won't be rate limited if it changes the color every 1 Minute